# #collection using contentBinding does not automatically update when rendering in a tbody

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm new with emberjs so it may be possible that I totally missed a few things.

I am trying to render the body of a table with content I retrieve from an Ajax request.

I use an ArrayController and a {{#collection}} in my view that I bind to the content of the controller (as the doc suggests).

It works when I set an initial value to `content` inside my `ArrayController` but it doesn't automatically update when I call `.set('content', [...])`.

Note that it only fails when I set the `tagName` of my view to `'tobdy'`, it works if for example I use `'pre'` (or pretty much anything else).

JSFiddles that show that issue:

- http://jsfiddle.net/midu/DjxG4/10/ (with `tbody`, should update after 2s, but doesn't)
- http://jsfiddle.net/midu/DjxG4/11/ (with `pre`, updates after 2s)

My questions are:

- is this a bug or did I not understand how it should be working?
- any advice for rendering the body of a table in a template?

This is what my code looks like:

index.html

```html
<table id="the-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>status</th>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>url</th>
    <th># messages</th>
    <th>judging status</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="submissions">
    {{#collection contentBinding="App.submissionsController"}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{content.status}}</td>
        <td>{{content.title}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{content.url}}">note</a></td>
        <td>{{content.nbMessages}}</td>
        <td>{{content.judgingStatus}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/collection}}
</script>
```

index.js

```js
var App = Em.Application.create({
  ready: function () {
    App.submissionsController.index();
    this._super();
  }
});

// model
App.Submission = Em.Object.extend({
  title: null,
  judgingStatus: null,
  status: null,
  url: null,
  nbMessages: 0
});

// controller... not really.
App.submissionsController = Em.ArrayController.create({
  content: [ App.Submission.create({title: 'kevin', status: 'a', judgingStatus: 'b', url: 'http://google.com', nbMessages: 1}) ],

  index: function () {
    // simulates data that arrives to the page after a few seconds (think ajax request)
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      App.submissionsController.set('content', [
          App.Submission.create({title: 'stefano', status: 'c', judgingStatus: 'd', url: 'http://stackoverflow.com', nbMessages: 2})
      ]);
    }, 2000);
  }
});

Em.View.create({
  templateName: 'submissions',
  tagName: 'tbody'
}).appendTo('#the-table');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I did to fix the code which can be seen on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/algesten/DjxG4/12/).

1. I would intermittently get `uncaught exception: Error: <Ember.View:ember161> - Unable to find template "submissions"` because the handlebar script is not evaluated before the app is inserted into the DOM. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222537/why-does-this-ember-js-app-fail-in-firefox/9223823#comment11627478_9223823).
2. Change the view to `{{#each}}` instead of the deprecated `{{#collection}}`. I haven't found a definite source on the deprecation – but it's indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531820/how-to-bind-value-form-input-select-to-attribute-in-controller) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636790/ember-js-how-do-i-access-a-specific-item-in-a-collectionview).

Comment: Awesome! that works, thanks! I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/488) to update the documentation of `ArrayController`.